# updating a row of data sqlite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to update my database. It is not really updating. I think it is due to my update command

my main activity is a listview activity. I have a button on the action bar that basically starts a new activity with two editboxes. So once I click that button, I create a new database item. It is originally set to two empty strings. On my second activity, I have a save button that is supposed to save my changes into the textboxes

so after my main activity takes me to my second activity, the code is as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note);

    // if new then create new db, else retrieve old database, right now
    // assume everything is new

    db = new DBHandler(this);
    nowAdd = new UENote("", "");
    db.addNote(nowAdd);
}
```

i update my nowAdd contact strings through this function

```
    public void updateColumnData() {
    // gets the strings from edittext
    EditText textTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText textSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    // converts the string
    String titleString = textTitle.getText().toString();
    String subjectString = textSubject.getText().toString();

    nowAdd.setSubject(subjectString);
    nowAdd.setTitle(titleString);

    db.updateNote(nowAdd);

}
```

the update note function is as follows

```
    public int updateNote(UENote note) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, note.getSubject());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE1, values, KEY_ID + " = ? ",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(note.getID()) });
}
```

Comment: Did you ever try using the DAO design ? for example GreenDAO can help you create your database module real quick and clean : http://greendao-orm.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the **id** you are passing in the `db.update()` is really the same one that you want to update. From the code snippet, it's not obvious how you are getting the value of `note.getID()`. Are you making query for empty record to get the **id**?

Assuming that `KEY_ID` is an `auto incremented primary key`, I would then debug `getID()` to check if it returns the same **id** of the record you wanted to update.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i thought KEY_ID was supposed to be the string "_id". I will check that note.getID() does return the correct id though

Comment: you are correct, the get ID is somehow returning zero. my get ID method is just  public long getID() {
  return this.id;
 }

Comment: do you know why it is returning zero?

Comment: okay i know why, when i add the element, the id is not immediately set, it is zero, at leaste when i try to get the id. However, when I use the getNUMNOTES() -- function that i wrote to get the total number of notes, i realized that it is incremented at the top (so if i have 4 items, the next one would return 5). anyway thats problem solved. I still need to figure out how to return the rowid

Comment: Great to hear that you found the issue.